# Reading from more than one line after keyword?

Tags: python

I have an output file which prints out a matrix of numeric data. I need to search through this file for the identifier at the start of each data set, which is:

```
GROUP      1 FIRST      1 LAST    163
```

Here GROUP 1 is the first column of the matrix, FIRST 1 is the first non-zero element of this matrix in position 1, and LAST 163 is the last non-zero element of the matrix in position 163. The matrix doesn't necessarily end at this LAST value - in this case there are 172 values.

I want to read this data into a simpler form to work with. Here is an example of the first two column results:

```
GROUP      1 FIRST      1 LAST    163
  7.150814E-02  9.866657E-03  8.500540E-04  1.818338E-03  2.410691E-03  3.284499E-03  3.011986E-03  1.612432E-03
  1.674247E-03  3.436244E-03  3.655873E-03  4.056876E-03  4.560725E-03  2.462454E-03  2.567764E-03  5.359393E-03
  5.457415E-03  2.679373E-03  2.600020E-03  2.491592E-03  2.365089E-03  2.228494E-03  5.792616E-03  1.623274E-03
  1.475062E-03  1.331820E-03  1.195052E-03  2.832699E-03  7.298341E-04  6.301271E-04  1.377459E-03  1.048925E-03
  1.677453E-04  3.580640E-04  1.575301E-04  1.150545E-04  1.197719E-04  2.950028E-05  5.380539E-05  1.228784E-05
  1.627659E-05  4.522051E-05  7.736908E-06  1.758838E-05  8.161204E-06  6.103670E-06  6.431876E-06  1.585671E-06
  4.110246E-06  4.512924E-07  2.775227E-06  5.107739E-07  1.219448E-06  1.653674E-07  4.429047E-07  4.837661E-07
  2.036820E-07  3.449548E-07  1.457648E-07  4.494116E-07  1.629392E-07  1.300509E-07  1.730199E-07  8.130338E-08
  1.591993E-08  5.457638E-08  1.713141E-08  7.806754E-09  1.154869E-08  3.545961E-09  2.862203E-09  2.289470E-09
  4.324002E-09  2.243199E-09  2.627165E-09  2.273119E-09  1.973867E-09  1.710714E-09  1.468845E-09  1.772236E-09
  1.764492E-09  1.004393E-09  1.044698E-09  5.201382E-10  2.660613E-10  3.012732E-10  2.630323E-10  4.381052E-10
  2.521794E-10  9.213524E-11  2.619283E-10  3.591906E-11  1.449830E-10  1.867363E-11  1.230445E-10  1.108149E-11
  2.775004E-11  1.156249E-11  4.393752E-11  5.318751E-11  6.815569E-12  1.817489E-11  2.044674E-11  2.044673E-11
  1.931080E-11  1.931076E-11  1.817484E-11  2.044668E-11  5.486837E-12  7.681572E-12  1.536314E-11  7.132886E-12
  8.230253E-12  1.426577E-11  1.426577E-11  4.389468E-12  5.925780E-12  2.853153E-12  2.853153E-12  5.706307E-12
  5.706307E-12  2.194733E-12  3.292099E-12  5.267358E-12  2.194733E-12  3.072626E-12  4.828412E-12  4.389466E-12
  4.389465E-12  1.097366E-11  2.194732E-12  1.316839E-11  2.194732E-12  1.608784E-11  1.674222E-11  1.778860E-11
  6.993074E-12  2.622402E-12  9.090994E-12  5.769285E-12  1.573441E-12  6.861030E-12  4.782885E-12  8.768619E-13
  2.311727E-12  3.188589E-12  4.393636E-12  3.844430E-12  4.256331E-12  1.235709E-12  2.746020E-12  2.746020E-12
  8.238059E-13  2.608719E-12  1.445203E-12  4.817344E-13  1.445203E-12  7.609642E-14  2.536547E-13  2.000924E-13
  7.075681E-14  7.075681E-14  3.056704E-14
GROUP      2 FIRST      2 LAST    168
  6.740271E-02  8.310813E-03  3.609403E-03  1.307012E-03  2.949375E-03  3.605043E-03  1.612647E-03  1.640960E-03
  3.597806E-03  4.022993E-03  4.289805E-03  4.480576E-03  2.352539E-03  2.415121E-03  5.018262E-03  5.188098E-03
  2.589224E-03  2.546116E-03  2.472462E-03  2.374431E-03  2.260519E-03  5.981164E-03  1.700972E-03  1.556116E-03
  1.410140E-03  1.273499E-03  3.061941E-03  7.995844E-04  6.967963E-04  1.553994E-03  1.216266E-03  1.997540E-04
  4.426460E-04  1.990445E-04  1.470610E-04  1.539762E-04  3.814900E-05  7.024764E-05  1.611156E-05  2.136422E-05
  5.984886E-05  1.035646E-05  2.363444E-05  1.105747E-05  8.308678E-06  8.789299E-06  2.257693E-06  5.807418E-06
  6.248625E-07  3.822327E-06  6.987942E-07  1.660586E-06  2.240283E-07  5.983062E-07  6.513773E-07  2.735403E-07
  4.614998E-07  1.940877E-07  5.895136E-07  2.081549E-07  1.662117E-07  2.316650E-07  1.101916E-07  2.162701E-08
  7.493990E-08  2.341661E-08  1.072330E-08  1.606536E-08  4.945307E-09  3.936301E-09  3.147244E-09  5.945972E-09
  3.108514E-09  3.682241E-09  3.210760E-09  2.795020E-09  2.436545E-09  2.118219E-09  2.612622E-09  2.586657E-09
  1.432507E-09  1.457386E-09  7.264341E-10  3.803348E-10  4.514677E-10  3.959518E-10  6.541553E-10  3.707172E-10
  1.334816E-10  3.875547E-10  5.294296E-11  2.294557E-10  2.790137E-11  1.719152E-10  1.408339E-11  3.526731E-11
  1.469469E-11  5.583990E-11  6.759567E-11  8.766360E-12  2.337697E-11  2.629908E-11  2.629908E-11  2.483802E-11
  2.483802E-11  2.337697E-11  2.629908E-11  7.112706E-12  9.957791E-12  1.991557E-11  9.246516E-12  1.066906E-11
  1.849303E-11  1.849303E-11  5.690165E-12  7.681722E-12  3.698607E-12  3.698607E-12  7.397214E-12  7.397214E-12
  2.845082E-12  4.267624E-12  6.828199E-12  2.845082E-12  3.983115E-12  6.259180E-12  5.690165E-12  5.690165E-12
  1.422541E-11  2.845082E-12  1.707049E-11  2.845082E-12  2.095991E-11  2.193285E-11  2.330364E-11  1.096642E-11
  4.112407E-12  1.425635E-11  8.906802E-12  2.429128E-12  1.106603E-11  8.097092E-12  1.484468E-12  3.913596E-12
  5.398063E-12  8.624785E-12  7.546689E-12  8.355261E-12  2.425721E-12  5.390492E-12  5.390492E-12  1.617147E-12
  5.120967E-12  2.710198E-12  9.033993E-13  2.710198E-12  3.744092E-13  1.248030E-12  6.614939E-13  4.359798E-13
  4.359798E-13  1.364861E-13  4.856661E-15  4.856661E-15  4.856661E-15  4.856661E-15  4.856661E-15
```

What I have at the moment works, except it only reads in the first line after the GROUP keyword line. How can I make it continue reading the data in until it reaches the next GROUP keyword?

```
file_name = "test_data.txt"

import re
import io

group_pattern = re.compile(r"GROUP +\d+ FIRST +(?P<first>\d+) LAST +(?P<last>\d+)")


def read_data_from_file(file_name, start_identifier, end_identifier):
    results = []
    longest = 0

    with open(file_name) as file:
        t = file.read()
        t=t[t.find('MACRO'):]
        t=t[t.find(start_identifier)+len(start_identifier):t.find(end_identifier)]
        t=io.StringIO(t)
        for line in t:
            match = group_pattern.search(line)
            if match:
                first = int(match.group('first'))
                last = int(match.group('last'))
                data = [float(value) for value in next(t).split()]
                row = [0.0] * last
                for i, value in enumerate(data, start=first-1):
                    row[i] = value
                longest = max(longest, len(row))
                results.append(row)

    for row in results:
        if len(row) < longest:
            row.extend([0.0] * (longest-len(row)))
    return results

start_identifier = "SCATTER MOMENT      1"
end_identifier = "SCATTER MOMENT      2"

results = read_data_from_file(file_name, start_identifier, end_identifier)
print(results)
```

What I want the code to produce is a matrix with just the numerical data. In this case it would be size [2x168] but my full data set is [172x172]. I want every GROUP to be read in as a row of the matrix, and zeroes filled into every element not specified in the output data. The current code does almost all of this, except that it only reads the first line of data after the GROUP keyword line.

Comment: When I try to run your code I'm getting a lot of errors. Is this all the code for this? I've tried to fix it but now idk what `longest` is suppose to be cause its not defined.

Comment: Edited the question to include the full code rather than a snippet, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Great the code is running. So one last bit and I think I can help. What is it you want this script to return? A list of the headers? An object with the headers and the data underneath? Right now the code is returns an empty list. If you can, edit your question to include a small version of what you expect to get back from this function.

Comment: I've edited to add an explanation, hopefully this helps to clarify what I need it to do. My code works almost perfectly, it just needs to read more lines of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a look at the data you provided in your question. I found what I think is a better and simpler way of pulling those data points out of that file. However I noticed that you have some other code thats looking for other things in the file as well but those weren't in the test data you posted. So you may have to adapt this a little to work with your dataset.

```
def read_data_from_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        index = -1
        matrices = []

        # Iterate over the file line by line via iter. Reduces memory usage
        for line in fp:

            # Since headers are always on their own line and data points always being with
            # two spaces we can just look for lines that start with two spaces.
            # If we find a line without these spaces then its the header line, add a new
            # list to matrices and add one to index
            if not line.startswith('  '):
                index += 1
                matrices.append([])

            else:
                # Splice str at index 2 to ignore first two spaces
                # Then split by two spaces to get each data point
                str_data_points = line[2:].split('  ')

                # Map the string data points to a floats
                float_data_points = map(lambda s: float(s), str_data_points)

                # Add those float data points to the list in matrices via index
                matrices[index].extend(float_data_points)

        max_matrix_length = max(map(lambda matrix: len(matrix), matrices))

        for matrix in matrices:
            matrix.extend([0.0] * (max_matrix_length - len(matrix)))

        return matrices
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! The data file is much larger than the snippet I posted so I have to search for the start and end points of the data I need to avoid working with the entire file. I hadn't thought of searching using the number of spaces but this is much simpler so thank you for the help! EDIT: The only issue here is that the code doesn't fill in the zero values in the matrix?

Comment: @UnaDavies Check out my answer for the full solution

Comment: @UnaDavies Sorry didn't see that you wanted zero padded. I added a zero pad at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to **read the data from the `.txt` file** and **produce a matrix-like output (0.0 padded at the end of each group)**

```
import re

def read_data_from_file(filepath):
    GROUP_DATA = []
    MAX_ELEMENT_COUNT = 0
    
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if 'GROUP' in line:
                GROUP_DATA.append([])
                MAX_ELEMENT_COUNT = max(MAX_ELEMENT_COUNT, int(re.findall(r'\d+', line)[-1]))
            else:
                values = line.split(' ')
                for value in values:
                    try:
                        GROUP_DATA[-1].append(float(value))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass

    for DATA in GROUP_DATA:
        if len(DATA) < MAX_ELEMENT_COUNT:
            DATA += [0.0] * (MAX_ELEMENT_COUNT - len(DATA))

    return GROUP_DATA
```

For the data in the given question saved into `data.txt`, the output would be as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np ------------------------------> Just to check the output shape
>>> mat = read_data_from_file('data.txt')
>>> np.shape(mat)
(2, 168) <-------------------------------------------- Output shape as expected
```

The Output Matrix's size is flexible to the given data